# Kafka - stop retrying on ConnectException

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a kafka producer defined like

```
public KafkaMessageProducer(String kafkaHost, String kafkaPort, Map<String, String> map) {
        this.kafkaTopic = map;
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaHost + ":" + kafkaPort);
        producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    }
```

And I am sending message using following code. (tried using callback also).

```
public void sendMessage(String topic, RestCommonResource resultToken) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode  jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(resultToken);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, jsonNode.toString());
        producer.send(record);

    }
```

But if kafka server is down and producer publishes a message, program gets stuck in infinite loop with following exception:

```
WARN  [2018-09-13 06:27:59,589] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: Error in I/O with localhost/127.0.0.1
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
! at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:238) ~[kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

If there any property that can be set to stop this retrying and drop the message.

Comment: For that matter, I did try `properties.put("retries", "1");`. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

> Currently if a Kafka client loses a connection with brokers it will wait for **reconnect.backoff.ms** milliseconds before attempting to reconnect.
>
> While this strategy works well when a client is disconnected for a short time if a single broker or the entire cluster become unavailable for a long time all clients will quickly generate a lot of connections.
>
> In addition, developers have limited control over a client which constantly loses its connections with the cluster.

I think this topic useful for you: [Add custom policies for reconnect attempts to NetworkdClient](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-53+-+Add+custom+policies+for+reconnect+attempts+to+NetworkdClient)

> **reconnect.backoff.ms**  : The base amount of time to wait before attempting to reconnect to a given host. This avoids repeatedly connecting to a host in a tight loop. This backoff applies to all connection attempts by the client to a broker.
>
> **reconnect.backoff.max.ms** : The maximum amount of time in milliseconds to wait when reconnecting to a broker that has repeatedly failed to connect. If provided, the backoff per host will increase exponentially for each consecutive connection failure, up to this maximum. After calculating the backoff increase, 20% random jitter is added to avoid connection storms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following Producer property too

```
props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "10000");
```

With `reconnect.backoff.ms`, the `WARN`ing will appear only once.

Regarding [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs),

> `reconnect.backoff.ms`
>  The base amount of time to wait before attempting
>   to reconnect to a given host. This avoids repeatedly connecting to a
>   host in a tight loop. This backoff applies to all connection attempts
>   by the client to a broker.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to limit the lifetime of the sending message [delivery.timeout.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#delivery.timeout.ms).

> An upper bound on the time to report success or failure after a call
>   to send() returns